# System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); on Visual Studio C# 2010 Express edition

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I have a windows service where I use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); to debug the service. It worked on VS 2010 Pro RC, not on the express edition...

Is there a way to debug a windows service with express edition ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't aware that you could do that. The way that I normally do it is that I add some command line options to the service, so if it's started as `[servicename].exe -c` it starts as a normal executable and then I just set -c as the startup parameter in Visual Studio.

So in my main I've got something similar to this:

```
if(IsConsole)
   ExecuteTheProcess();
else
{
   ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = { new MyService(); }
   ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
}
```

Comment: I finally followed this tutorial : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/DebugWinServices.aspx

Same idea but with preprocessor instructions !

Thanks